# Will `qsub` run my jobs sequentially?

Tags: scripting, qsub

Assume a script including the following content is passed to `qsub` as `qsub myscript.sh`

```
#PBS -N Job_name
#PBS -l walltime=10:30,mem=320kb
#PBS -m be
#
step1 arg1 arg2
step2 arg3 arg4
```

Will `step1` and `step2` run in parallel over different nodes or sequentially on the allocated resource?

Answer (score 1):

`step1` and `step2` are two commands within the same job.  The commands will be executed one after the other subject to the `-l walltime=10:30,mem=320kb` restriction on the whole job.[¹](https://linuxcommandlibrary.com/man/qsub)